# Legend Error In Errorbars Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, errorbar

```
legend(errorbars, {'5-15 Percent Exiting Agents', '25-35 Percent Exiting Agents','55-65 Percent Exiting Agents','x','y','z'},'Location','NorthWest');
```

Gives the error:

Error using legend (line 120)
Invalid argument. Type 'help legend' for more information.

```
>> errorbars

errorbars =

    0.0011    0.0012    1.0012    2.0012    3.0012    4.0012
```

I have no idea why this error occurs. As it has 6 labels for six errorbars!

Also, posting full code:

```
for k=1:2,    %x-axis variables
    for i=1:size(StringDes,2), %y-axis outputs
        errorbar_index=0;
        set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
        for j=1:3,  % two loops for 6 errorbars
            for z=1:2,
                errorbar_index=errorbar_index+1;
                filter2= (pe{z}<upp(j) & pe{z} >lowp(j));
                dataset=Descriptors{z}{i};
                var= Variables{z}(:,k);
                y=dataset(filter2);
                x=var(filter2);
                if(k==2)
                    range=rangeValues_ks;
                else
                    range=rangeValues_ke;
                end
                filter3=(ismember(x,range)) ;
                [vals, ~, id] = unique(x(filter3));
                m = accumarray(id, y(filter3), [], @mean);
                s = accumarray(id, y(filter3), [], @std);
                errorbars(errorbar_index)=errorbar(vals,m,s,colors(j), 'LineStyle',linestyle{z},'Marker',marker{z},'LineWidth',linewidth(z));
            end            
            xlabel(StringVar(k));
            ylabel(StringDes(i));
            hold all;            
        end
        filename=char(strcat(StringDesFileName(i),StringVarFileName(k)));
        legend(errorbars, {'5-15 Percent Exiting Agents', '25-35 Percent Exiting Agents','55-65 Percent Exiting Agents','x','y','z'},'Location','NorthWest');
        title('');
        print(gcf,strcat(parent_folder,'/',filename),'-dpng','-r375' );
        close gcf;
    end
end
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `errorbars` argument from the `legend` call?

Comment: so have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, solves it! Sry  for nt replying before. Got lost with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't associate a legend with multiple entries from a `ErrorBar` array (here a `1x6` array). What you can do is associate that legend with the axes in which the `ErrorBar` objects were created. They are indeed `Children` of the axes, so if you want you can associate the legend with their `Parent`, i.e. the axes.

So what you can do is change the problematic line to either this:

```
legend(gca, {'5-15 Percent Exiting Agents', '25-35 Percent Exiting Agents','55-65 Percent Exiting Agents','x','y','z'},'Location','NorthWest');
```

or this:

```
legend(get(errorbars(1),'Parent'), {'5-15 Percent Exiting Agents', '25-35 Percent Exiting Agents','55-65 Percent Exiting Agents','x','y','z'},'Location','NorthWest');
```

Note that if you only have 1 active axes in your working session than you can omit `gca` altogether in the 1st case.

Comment: Thanks!! Does the job.